# Angular: how to force EventEmitter to flush in test

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-event-emitter

I have following Angular test:

```js
it('should pass', fakeAsync(() => {
      let a;
      const eventEmitter1 = of('A');
      eventEmitter1.subscribe(v => a = v);

      let b;
      const eventEmitter2 = new EventEmitter();
      eventEmitter2.emit('B');
      eventEmitter2.subscribe(v => b = v);

      tick();
      flush();

      console.log(a); // Outputs A
      console.log(b); // outputs undefined

      expect(a).toBe('A');
      expect(b).toBe('B'); // How to make the test to pass here?
    }));
```

I am not able to flush the `eventEmitter2` and test **fails**. How can I flush the `EventEmmiter.emit()` in a test?

Note: This is simplified version of my test that uses `async` pipe from Angular that uses `EventEmitter` internally.

```
"@angular/core": "^8.2.14"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `eventEmitter2.emit('B');` after `eventEmitter2.subscribe(v => b = v);`

```
eventEmitter2.subscribe(v => b = v);
eventEmitter2.emit('B');
```

As `EventEmitter` is an extension to the `Subject`. It won't publish previous events to new subscribers.